# Scala toArray function returning

Tags: scala

I am trying to fetch the nbr from a string given. I have used regex object. But Its giving me address value. Please explain why toArray is not giving the result.

```
ackage Phase1Training
object ScalaRegex {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        val numPattern = "[0-9]+".r
        val address ="123 washington Road 102"
        var zip = numPattern.findFirstIn(address)

        println(zip)
        **var matches = numPattern.findAllMatchIn(address).toArray** //Why this is giving the object address.
        println (matches)
        matches.foreach(println)  //This is perfectly working.
```

Some(123)
**[Lscala.util.matching.Regex$Match;@30097f5f**
123
102

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `println` on an `Array`.  The `println` method on many object is not meant to be displayed, and is basically unimplemented.  Try `mkString` on collections, which accepts an optional string delimiter:

```
myArray.mkString // e.g. "el1el2el3"
myArray.mkString(",") // e.g. "el1,el2,el2"
```

And then print that.

Comment: It is implemented in some sense, it's just that default implementation that comes from the very top of class hierarchy (Object) is not what you would expect to see normally